# old gcc version for boost

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-construction, boost, version

When I try to use boost on an old Linux system, I get the message:

> Compiler not configured - please reconfigure

The version of my gcc is:

> gcc version 2.9-gnupro-99r1

And in boost's gcc.hpp file I see:

```
// versions check:
// we don't know gcc prior to version 2.90:
#if (__GNUC__ == 2) && (__GNUC_MINOR__ < 90)
#  error "Compiler not configured - please reconfigure"
#endif
```

So, are gcc 2.9 and 2.90 actually the same thing? If yes - can I just update the gcc.hpp? And if not, how can I still use boost?

---

EDIT:

I actually tried to change `(__GNUC_MINOR__ < 90)` to `(__GNUC_MINOR__ < 9)`.
Seems like 2.9 and 2.90 are not the same because now I get compilation errors.

Seems like the errors are because this compiler doesn't support the `\` (line extension) characters in the preprocessor macros. These line breaks are used by boost in many places.

Comment: Can't you install boost from the old linux version's repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't upgrade the compiler, downgrade the sources. Not really very sensible advice, but still, it might work.

Old Boost releases are found here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/

Good luck!

PS: if it's the line breaks that are killing you, maybe you can try to remove them (if there aren't too many)

Answer (score 2):

All C and C++ compilers have supported the \ in macros since the year dot, so that is not the problem. I think it unlikely that Boost will support 2.9x compilers (but who knows?)  - why not simply upgrade the compiler? GCC is now on version 4.5, so yours is ridiculously outdated.

You might also want to look at [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/status/compiler_status.html), which documents Boost's compiler support.

Comment: I can't upgrade the compiler in this case, so will be looking for another solution..